# SPI (15 MHz Signal) on two Layer PCB

Tags: pcb, spi, ground, transmission-line, high-speed

I want to do a MIDI Controller which uses 15 MHz SPI between a Teensy 3.6 and 74HC595 / 74HC165 Shift Registers to read a button Matrix. The code is finished and the PCB would be the next step. I have read a lot about 50 Ohm controlled impedance transmission lines, return paths on ground planes, etc.

However, as I am completely new to this I have some simple (noob) questions:

1. Does the return path really matter this much? I have attached a picture of my breadboard layout. Wires are going very chaotic and just to test stability I used 60 cm wires for the SPI. It just works fine. Do I have to be so much more careful when using a PCB? I would like to stick to two layers because it is much cheaper. My general Sketch runs with 4 kHz and I have some PWM at 29 kHz. There is nothing going on in parallel during the SPI transfer. I propably will not have space for a proper ground plane as I also use motor faders, encoders and stuff and they will become a lot more than on the prototype  and therefore, will need lot's of connections.
2. Does crosstalk to other signal matter if I don't need to evaluate them at the same time?
3. If you say it won't work without a good return path, can I replace the ground plane with a ground track running close to the SPI signal line? Unforunately I found nothing about that.

According the Saturn PCB Toolikit even with 75 MHz (I considered that because I was not sure if 15 Mhz would mean a bandwith of 75 MHz)  and a Lambda of 1/10 I can go approx. 15 Inches without considering it to be a transmission line. I think I just can't run clock and signal in parallel to avoid cross talk in between them. Perhaps running a ground track in between them & keeping them approx. the same length will be good.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You are mixing things. The 50 ohm impedance doesn't apply to SPI, since it's not a 50 ohm system. You are asking about PCB, but showing a bunch of 60cm wires. Then asking about return path, ground plane,...etc without a PCB example and schematics?

Comment: "... My general Sketch runs with 4 kHz and I have some PWM at 29 kHz. ..." Do you mean 4 MHz?

Comment: Scanning slow things like button matrix with 15 MHz SPI is overkill. 60cm of random wires will be a problem at 15 MHz clock, but also for slower SPI clocks. The problem is not the speed of the clock frequency, the problem is the speed of clock edges which can cause reflections and ringing and corrupt the transmission even with 1 Hz clock.

Comment: The PCB shall replace all the wires. 
Here is a sketch of my schematic: 
https://www.docdroid.net/M3qSU2D/midi-controller-plan-pdf 
However, it's the schematic of the protpype. On the final piece a lot more components will add.
I wonder if when this works fine with 60 cm single wires w/o ground, why it souldn't work on the board with lets say 20 cm traces (without ground plane)

The arduino sketch loops approx. 4000 times a second. In the sketch I use PWM with 29 kHz and SPI with 15 MHz. I use SPI because slower protocols will slow down the overall sketch to 1000 times a second or so....

Comment: @Didda if you need 15 MHz SPI so that your main loop does not run too slowly just because you need to read UI buttons, have you considered you should perhaps do something differently? But anyway, if you don't have a ground plane beneath the SPI signals, it could be wired like flat flex cabling, surround each signal wire with a ground wire.

Comment: Warning people - the docdroid link causes dodgy pop-ups with fake windows.
@didda - don't post stuff on dodgy sites.

Comment: With a 15 MHz clock, using your 5X, or 75 MHz max frequency content as a design constraint (which is a bit overkill, but better safe than sorry), and 20 cm trace lengths on your PCB, you do not have to worry about controlled impedance for any of your traces.  And a good return/ground return path or system is a good design technique regardless of the frequencies being used.

Comment: Well if it works on a breadboard it will be hard to make it worse on a PCB!

Comment: Regarding the ground plane in a 2-layer configuration, I would advise to make a best effort to have fairly direct return paths, even if you do route some signals on the bottom layer. It's probably going to be OK to have a few short traces or islands on the bottom layer, but avoid long tracks cutting across the return paths.

Comment: For prototyping and hobby projects, 4 layer PCBs are usually less than 1 dollar per board more expensive than 2 layer from the budget PCB houses.  If you were going to make 1 million units maybe cost savings would matter, but here it doesn't.  Use a 4 layer board with power and ground planes.  You'll save hours of work routing and have much better signal integrity.

Comment: Thank you all. 
Unfortunately with the size I approx. need a four layer pcb costs approx. $75 while a two layer will only cost approx. $35.
I will have a try with two layer pcb. If I understand correct I can place a ground trace as retrun path next to the signal on the same layer. Perhaps on both sides like a flex cable ... gnd - sign - gnd ...
I hope, like Steve Sh and Damien mentioned, that I do not have to worry about controlled impedance here and that it should work on PCB whan it also works on Breadboard.
If not I will have to do it again with four layer, but I really don't hope so :)